# How to make other server race for getting the output in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, network-programming

I have written 3 servers with threading with different Lists which include different tasks in them connected to each other 
and I am connecting with them with client program written like below to see if my specific task is in the one of the server:

```
import socket
import sys

HOST, PORT = "172.16.27.183", 9999
data = " ".join(sys.argv[1:])
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
    sock.sendall(data)
    response = sock.recv(1024)
    print "Sent:     {}".format(data)
    print "Received: {}".format(response)
finally:
    sock.close()
```

Now if the connected server is busy I want to make an option on my client code so the other servers can give the clients the answer on time(faster) and I don't have to wait for one server.

Comment: check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)

Comment: could you explain how should i use it in python I don't know how? and do you know an easier way to learn and do it?

Comment: Read the wiki page first, and you would know why it's hard to answer your question.